# Is it necessary to activate Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

I installed a MSDN copy of Windows 8, after a couple of months I realized that indeed it's unnecessary to activate the OS. All the difference I can see is the warning message "Activate window 8..." in the bottom right corner, which is not a problem for me. May be some functions are being disabled, but I have no problem in my daily use.

So I'm wondering if it's the same in the case of Windows 10?

Comment: Windows 10 will automatically activate.  Windows 8 technically will attempt to automatically activate.  In both cases if there is a problem, that problem, will prevent it from activation.  In both cases you should address the problem and activate your installation.

Answer (score 1):

You won't need to activate your copy of Windows 10.

There are just **two limitations** for a non-activated Windows:

1. A **watermark** in the lower right corner
2. **No personalization**, like custom desktop wallpapers, lock screen, etc.

You will even receive updates.

[Source](http://www.windowscentral.com/you-do-not-need-activate-windows-10)

Comment: Do you have a source to validate your claim?

Comment: Will you accept a german source?

Comment: Found a english one... http://www.windowscentral.com/you-do-not-need-activate-windows-10

Comment: It's not for me. Source is to validate your answer. Good job.